# What's wrong with my program? Stuck in calculation loop or failed function call?

Tags: loops, math, function-call

This is my program. I don't understand what's wrong in it. After I give the inputs nothing happens. I am guessing that the program got stuck in calculation loop or I am unable to call fact function in the loop. Ideas on where the problem should be?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int fact(int a)
{
    int f=0;
    for(int i=1; i<=a;i++)
    f=f*i;
}

main()
{
    double x,temp1,temp2,sine;
    int p,n;
    temp1=temp2=0;
    cout<<"Enter the value of x: ";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"\nEnter the length of series: ";
    cin>>n;
    if(n%2==0)
    {
        for(p=1;p<=n-1;p+4)
        {
            temp1=temp1+(pow(x,p)/fact(p));
        }
        for(p=3;p<=n-1;p+4)
        {
            temp2=(temp2+pow(x,p)/fact(p))*(-1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(p=1;p<=n;p+4)
        {
            temp1=temp1+(pow(x,p)/fact(p));
        }
        for(p=3;p<=n;p+4)
        {
            temp2=-(temp2+pow(x,p)/fact(p));
        }
    }
    sine=temp1+temp2;
    cout<<"\nsinx= "<<sine;
}
```

Comment: p = p+4 in for loop I guess

Comment: Yep, it was a problem with the increment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `p+4` doing in the increment section of the for loop? Also you aren't returning any values from `int fact()`.

Comment: Can't we use it in place of p++? I thought it was just a condition, moving it in to the loop worked. Thanks.

Comment: @PavanKGuduru `p++` is the same as `p=p+1`, not `p+1`.  There's an assignment that is also present.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
    int fact(int a)
{
    int f=1;
    for(int i=1; i<=a;i++)
    f=f*i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Changed it. But the problem was with increment in the loop.